# How to untar file only if my jar file is updated in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, tar

In chef, I want to untar a tarball to a specific directory, but only if my "new.jar" file within that specific directory has changed its contents or name.

The problem I am having is that I have an existing "new.jar" file in my node, but when I update ,y "new.jar"file within my "files" directory of my cookbook, and do my chef run, the jar file does not get updated, because the name and file size is the same, despite it being a newer version. How can I resolve this issue?

```rb
execute 'Untar' do
  command "tar zxvf #{sweeper_install_dir}/test.tar.gz -C #{dir}"
  not_if { ::File.exist?("#{dir}/new.jar") }
end
```

Comment: Try removing the `not_if` guard. Then `execute` will run every time and "untar" your jar file..

Answer (score 1):

looks like you struck at chicken and egg situation. so i understand you issue correctly, you have updated version of **test.tar.gz** and it is not been updating after chef since your server already have **new.jar** present inside the server.

The solution is you have to do things little different

1. first you have to download your **test.tar.gz** file if it is new.
2. unzip to destination if new file is downloaded.

That's it

```
remote_file "#{sweeper_install_dir}/test.tar.gz" do
  source 'http://somesite.com/test.tar.gz'
  action :create
  notifies :run, 'execute[Untar]', :immediately
end

execute 'Untar' do
  command "tar zxvf #{sweeper_install_dir}/test.tar.gz -C #{dir}"
  action: nothing
end
```